# Reputation gains for Teams not vertically aligned in daily summary in achievements dialog

Tags: bug, design, achievements-dialog, stack-overflow-for-teams

In the achievements dialog, the reputation gains/losses per site per day are aligned vertically, but for Stack Overflow for Teams the icon is too large, which pushes the '+12' in the screenshot below a few pixels downwards:

[image]

<sup>(apologies for the not-hand-drawn straight line)</sup>